# Calculate midpoint for hh:mm variable over the span of two days with no date

Tags: r, lubridate, chron

I would like to calculate the midpiont between falling asleep and waking up. I'm struggling a bit, because I have no date, just the time as hh:mm.

For example, if you go to bed at 2 a.m. and wake up at 10 a.m., the midpoint is 6 a.m.

Below is an example and I'd be glad for some help!

```
DF <- data.frame(time_start = c("23:45", "21:30", "22:00", "23:00", "00:30", "02:00"),
                 time_end = c("06:49", "06:30", "07:00", "09:00", "5:30", "10:00"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the two time objects to numeric, calculate their averages, and then convert them back to time objects.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DF %>%
  mutate_all(hm) %>%
  mutate(time_end = time_end + (time_end < time_start) * days(1),
         midpoint = seconds_to_period(as.numeric(time_start + time_end) / 2)) %>%
  mutate_all(~sprintf("%02d:%02d", hour(.), minute(.)))

#   time_start time_end midpoint
# 1      23:45    06:49    03:17
# 2      21:30    06:30    02:00
# 3      22:00    07:00    02:30
# 4      23:00    09:00    04:00
# 5      00:30    05:30    03:00
# 6      02:00    10:00    06:00
```